# Good evening, I have an error and I don't know why. "name with value "[object Object]" must be of type string" must be of type string

Tags: javascript, html, object, face

This is the variable (GRUPO_PERSONAS_ID)

```
const GRUPO_PERSONAS_ID = 'my-unique-person-group'
```

```
 console.log('-----------------------------------------');
 console.log('Person group');

await client.personGroup.create(GRUPO_PERSONAS_ID, {
            'name': GRUPO_PERSONAS_ID
        })
        .then(() => {

        }) 
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            throw err
        })
```

The previous code is the only one that I use, in fact I do not understand but it generates the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Snne.jpg)

**name with value "[object Object]" must be of type string.**

Comment: `{'name': GRUPO_PERSONAS_ID}` is an object and it can be assumed that you should pass a string there

Comment: Hello, I did not understand hahaha  :v. Is it preferable to put the text in quotes, than to call the variable that contains the text?

Comment: Help mee not understand

Comment: `client.personGroup.create` takes in 2 arguments.. the second argument you gave is called an object whereas it requires a string.. look at [datatypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)